# How to proceed next line while reading specific line?

Tags: python

I got file called 'datafile', which contains data like this:

```
tag
12
22
33
tag
234
1
23
43
tag
8
tag
0
12
```

The number of numbers between the "tag"s varies.

What I need to do is to access every first( or second) number (if exist) after "tag".

My uncompleted Python code:

```
f = open('datafile', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if line == 'tag':
        print('tag found!')
        # how can I access next number here?
```

How can I proceed to next line inside the for loop?

Comment: Your code already iterates over every line. Run `for line in f.readlines(): print(line.strip())` to demonstrate this.

Comment: That would print every line of the file. What I need to do is to access or print ONLY the first number after 'tag'

Comment: Add additional variable which hold state that tag was there eg. `wasTag = False` and if tag was found make it `True`. Also apply `if wasTag: ` and then `print(line)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to just reset a counter every time you encounter "tag":

```
k = 1 # or 2, or whatever
with open('datafile', 'r') as f:
    since_tag = 0
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == 'tag':
            print('tag found!')
            since_tag = 0
        if since_tag == k:
            print "kth number found: ", line
        since_tag += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an iterator fed into a generator.

```
def getFirstSecond(browser):
    for line in browser:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == 'tag':
            first = next(browser).strip()
            try:
                second = next(browser).strip()
            except StopIteration:
                second = None
            yield first, second if second != 'tag' else first, None
with open('datafile', 'r') as f:
    browser = iter(f)
    pairs = list(getFirstSecond(browser))
```

To answer your question, you proceed to the next line using the `next` function.

Note the use of the `with` statement; this is how you should be opening a file (it ensures the file is closed when you are done with it).